# The tooltip for the taskbar clock won't show up in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, notification-area

When I hover the mouse pointer over the clock in the Windows 7 taskbar, the tooltip flashes for a millisecond and then disappears. Sometimes it disappears so quickly that I won't even notice.

Tooltips for the other items in the notification area are all working normally.

Are there any settings or tools to fix this?

Comment: Try to reboot your computer

Comment: this is not new. i've had this problem for quit a week. rebooting wont help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you moving your cursor while hovering? If your cursor moves around too much, a hover might not be detected for very long (or at all).

These might also help:

[Set Tooltip duration via the Registry](http://www.ehow.com/how_8759396_set-balloon-tip-duration.html)

I'd also check out XdN Tweaker and [The Windows Club](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/list-freeware-releases-from-the-windows-club).

Comment: Thanks for answering but as I mentioned previously, every tooltip in the whole windows environment works as it should do except for the taskbar clock tooltip. I can set tooltip duration but it still won't work for the clock!

Comment: Maybe you could try adding/removing "Additional Clocks" from the tooltip via "Adjust date/time." There might be something wrong with what's being displayed in the tooltip, and forcing Windows to change what's in it might reset it somehow. Or, you could try left-clicking on the taskbar clock to bring up the calendar and animated clock. That would certainly last longer than the tooltip (in fact, it stays until you left-click on the taskbar clock again).

Comment: Thanks steven, Adding an additional clock did the trick. it's a little thing but I really missed it :)